# Writing NFC Card

Tags: flutter, nfc, flutter-plugin

I am using flutter to build my application to read and write the NFC cards I am using the flutter plugin NFC reader to read the cards but I couldn't find any way to write the NFC​ cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write NFC tags on ios where in android you can.

You might wanna use [Platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

`Platform channels` helps writing and communicating between platform-specific code and your Dart code

Here is a medium post regarding [writing an NFC tag on android](https://android.jlelse.eu/writing-to-a-nfc-tag-on-android-8d58f5e3c1fc)

Write it on android and connect it to dart using `Platform channels`